# Twitter cookies expiring - PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies, twitter

have this code that saves Twitter cookies so I can use it later, that is, I have a login system.

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->cookies = '';
$obj->location = '';

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com/',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR               => getcwd() . '/cookies/' . $username . '.txt',
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$obj) {
            if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^=]*)=([^;]*)/mi', $header, $matches)) {
                    $obj->cookies .= $matches[1] . '=' . $matches[2] . '; ';
                    $obj->{$matches[1]} = $matches[2];
                }
            }
            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]
);
$response = curl_exec($request);
```

The problem is that when you purchase these cookies later, they do not work, they expire, how do I renew or do not expire?

Comment: Use auto login with PHP its solved you Bro ?